# Mirror the image shown in preview zxing when scanning with front camera

Tags: c#, camera, uwp, zxing

I have this small scanner app built in UWP using zxing.net.mobile and cannot find a way to mirror image shown in preview while using front camera.

At the moment everything is working, just it is really hard to aim the QR code to the camera, because movement is inverse, not like in the mirror.
I couldn't find anything on internet, all results involve android or xamarin which is not what I look for. If any code or pics are required please ask. Any help will be appreciated

```
    var options = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions { TryHarder = true, AutoRotate = true, InitialDelayBeforeAnalyzingFrames = 3000, UseFrontCameraIfAvailable = true};
        options.PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat>() {
                                    BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE };
        var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner
        {
            TopText = "Turēt, lai noskenētu."
            //BottomText = "Tally Scan"
        };
        var result = await scanner.Scan(options);
```

Comment: Have you tried one of the options called `TryInverted`?

Comment: Yes I did, it does not change the preview image